# Не могу разобраться с перегрузкой в c#

Tags: c#

Вот следующий класс:

```
public class Array_
{
    private int[] value;
    public Array_(params int[] type)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref value, type.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < type.Length; i++)
        {
            value[i] = type[i];
        }
    }
    int[] add_value(params int[] values)
    {
        int[] res = new int[this.value.Length + values.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.value.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i] = this.value[i];
        }
        for (int i = this.value.Length; i < res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i] = values[res.Length - this.value.Length + i];
        }
        return res;
    }
    public static Array_ operator +(Array_ type) => new Array_(Conkak.summ_mass(this.value, type.value));
}
```

Класс Conkak от балды назвал для использования при совмещении массивов:

```
public class Conkak
{
    public static int[] summ_mass(int[] mass1, int[] mass2)
    {
        int[] res = new int[mass1.Length + mass2.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < mass1.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i] = mass1[i];
        }
        for (int i = mass1.Length; i < res.Length; i++)
        {
            res[i] = mass2[res.Length - mass1.Length + i];
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Однако у меня проблема со строчкой

```
public static Array_ operator +(Array_ type) => new Array_(Conkak.summ_mass(this.value, type.value));
```

В статическом методе я не могу использовать this, однако как мне указать на value в summ_mass()?

Comment: `new Conkak().summ_mass(...`?

Comment: что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: `public static Array_ operator +(Array_ left, Array_ right) => new Array_(Conkak.summ_mass(left.value, right.value));` ?

Comment: спасибо, разобрался. Не понял, что для оператора + нужны 2 аргумента.